# control textcase within section heading

Tags: sectioning, capitalization, ieeetran

I am using IEEE document class in conference mode. I want to use a special word: name of my protocol inside the section title. The word has the form: aBCD/eFGH. Since each word of the whole section heading is capitalized, this word also gets capitalized.

I have search this site and have tried to use package `textcase` but it does not help.

Comment: [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) sets the `\section` header in `\normalfont\normalsize\scshape`. Do you *just* want to remove the capitalization, or set it in a different font as well?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free ot visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of the site.

Comment: You might consider just sticking with your section title as it is. I think it's quite clear that the small capitals `A` and `E` are intended to be read as lowercase. A risk of setting them in lowercase proper is that you lose some typographical consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEEEtran` sets section headings in smallcaps. If you use `\textup{a}`, you can cancel the smallcaps temporarily. In the code snippet below, I have fixed the `a`, but left the `e` as a small capital, for comparison. Subsections and subsubsections aren't affected.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\begin{document}
\section{\textup{a}BCD/eFGH}
\subsection{aBCD/eFGH}
\subsubsection{aBCD/eFGH}
\end{document}
```

[image]